# Extract value from simple XML element (root only) using XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, linq-to-xml

My XML looks like this: (comes from a webservice)

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">36</int>
```

I need to get at the 36, and try to do it at follows:

```
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XDocument _xdoc = XDocument.Load(dataStream);    
return _xdoc.Element("int").Value;
```

But it can't find the element. returns a null value;

What is my mistake?

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your xml string is always one node..as in your code. You can try this way.

```
string xml = "<int xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">36</int>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            string val = doc.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the namespace:

```
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XDocument _xdoc = XDocument.Load(dataStream);    
var ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/";
return _xdoc.Element(ns + "int").Value;
```

Or simpler just using `XElement`:

```
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
return XElement.Load(dataStream).Value;
```